# Exercise: .each loops

Tags: ruby, loops, each

I was wondering if anyone can help me, i am having a tough time with this question in the tutorial learnhowtoprogram.com by epicodus. The question is....

Create a variable called my_fave_drink and set it equal to a String. Also create a variable to hold an empty Array and call it my_new_drink. Convert my_fave_drink to an Array of single letters. Now loop through each letter stored in that Array and push it into the my_new_drink Array three times. Then convert my_new_drink into a String, and set my_fave_drink equal to this new String. So if your favorite drink is "Pepsi", at the end of the loop it should be "PPPeeepppsssiii".

my solution is the following, but in order to get "cccoookkkeee", i need to type my_fav_drink after the loop, which is not what is asked for in the problem.

```
my_fave_drink = "coke"
my_new_drink = []
my_fave_drink = my_fave_drink.split("")
my_fave_drink.each() do |drink|
  3.times do 
  my_new_drink.push(drink)
  end
  my_fave_drink = my_new_drink.join()
end
```

Where am i going wrong? Thank you.

Comment: you were right, I think they mean "after" the each loop.  Meaning, if you move the the assignment of `my_fave_drink = my_new_drink.join()` to after the `end` you'll have your solution.

Comment: Yea i thought so too, was just worried i missed something. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Anthony answered the OP's question in the comments, but--just for kicks--here's an alternative solution using [`each_char`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-each_char):

```
my_fave_drink = "coke"
my_new_drink = ""
my_fave_drink.each_char { |char| my_new_drink << char*3}
```

Comment: Here's a one-liner, just for kicks, with ALL required steps :-) : `"water".each_char.with_object([]).each {|c, o| o << (c*3)} .join`